Coloring certain locations in a pattern in Python
I am generating a pattern with a square and coloring red and green at different locations. I would like to color the white spaces between different squares yellow and print the coordinates of these yellow squares. I have shown the output below including the full code. I would be grateful if somebody can help.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the grid size and the number of squares
grid_size = 4
square_size = 1  # Size of each square
gap = 0.1        # Gap between squares

# Create a new figure
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=80)

# Lists to store the coordinates of the rectangles
green_rectangles = []
red_rectangles = []

# Add yellow rectangles to fill the gaps before drawing the squares
for row in range(grid_size):
    for col in range(grid_size):
        # Calculate the coordinates for the bottom-left corner of the gap
        x = col * (square_size + gap)
        y = row * (square_size + gap)
        
        # Create a yellow rectangle for the gap
        if row < grid_size - 1:
            plt.Rectangle((x, y + square_size), square_size, gap, edgecolor='none', facecolor='yellow')
        if col < grid_size - 1:
            plt.Rectangle((x + square_size, y), gap, square_size + gap, edgecolor='none', facecolor='yellow')

# Loop through rows and columns to draw the squares
for row in range(grid_size):
    for col in range(grid_size):
        # Calculate the coordinates for the bottom-left corner of the square
        x = col * (square_size + gap)
        y = row * (square_size + gap)
        
        # Create a square using plt.Rectangle
        rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), square_size, square_size, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)

# Add green rectangles to fill the vertical gaps
for row in range(grid_size):
    for col in range(grid_size - 1):  # Exclude the last column
        x = (col + 1) * (square_size + gap) - gap
        y = row * (square_size + gap)
        green_rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), gap, square_size, edgecolor='none', facecolor='green')
        plt.gca().add_patch(green_rectangle)
        green_rectangles.append((x, y))

# Add red rectangles to fill the horizontal gaps
for row in range(grid_size - 1):  # Exclude the last row
    for col in range(grid_size):
        x = col * (square_size + gap)
        y = (row + 1) * (square_size + gap) - gap
        red_rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), square_size, gap, edgecolor='none', facecolor='red')
        plt.gca().add_patch(red_rectangle)
        red_rectangles.append((x, y))

# Print the coordinates of the red and green rectangles
print("Green rectangles:")
for coord in green_rectangles:
    print(coord)

print("\nRed rectangles:")
for coord in red_rectangles:
    print(coord)

# Set the aspect of the plot to be equal, so squares appear as squares
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')

# Set limits to accommodate the gaps
plt.xlim(0, grid_size * (square_size + gap))
plt.ylim(0, grid_size * (square_size + gap))

# Remove axis values
plt.gca().set_xticks([])
plt.gca().set_yticks([])

# Add grid lines for better visualization
plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)

# Show the plot
plt.show()



I think that matplotlib is not a suitable mean for such task. The coordinate-based painting is available in e.g. PyQt

With shapely, you can get the intersection of each "gridlines-like" combination :
from shapely import box
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.plotting import plot_polygon

bl = (0, 0)      # grid's bottom-left
grid_size = 4    # grid's initial size
square_size = 1  # sub-squares size 
gap = 0.1        # distance between ss

steps = [
    square_size + (square_size + gap) * i # round ?
    for i in range(grid_size // square_size - 1)
]
extent = grid_size + gap * (grid_size - 1) # round ?
square = box(bl[0], bl[1], bl[0] + extent, bl[1] + extent)

g_rects = [box(x, 0, x + gap, extent) for x in steps]
r_rects = [box(0, y, extent, y + gap) for y in steps]
y_rects = [r.intersection(g) for r in r_rects for g in g_rects]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), subplot_kw={"aspect": "equal"})

styles = {"alpha": 1, "add_points": False}

for lst, c in zip([g_rects, r_rects, y_rects], "gry"):
    for r in lst:
        plot_polygon(r, color=c, zorder=2, **styles, ax=ax)
else:
    plot_polygon(square, color="k", **styles, ax=ax)

NB: The coords can be obainted with map(lambda p: list(p.exterior.coords), y_rects)


The following code tries to simplify your approach.

draw red rectangles below each square, except for the first row
draw green rectangles to the left of each square, except for the first column
draw green gap squares to the left and below each square, except for the first row and column

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the grid size and the number of squares
grid_size = 4
square_size = 1  # Size of each square
gap = 0.1  # Gap between squares

# Create a new figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=80)

# Add yellow rectangles to fill the gaps before drawing the squares
for row in range(1, grid_size):
    for col in range(1, grid_size):
        # Calculate the coordinates for the bottom-left corner of the gap
        x = col * (square_size + gap)
        y = row * (square_size + gap)

        # Create a yellow rectangle for the gap
        rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), -gap, - gap, edgecolor='none', facecolor='gold')
        ax.add_patch(rectangle)

# Loop through rows and columns to draw the squares
for row in range(grid_size):
    for col in range(grid_size):
        # Calculate the coordinates for the bottom-left corner of the square
        x = col * (square_size + gap)
        y = row * (square_size + gap)

        # Create a square using plt.Rectangle
        rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), square_size, square_size, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rectangle)

# Add green rectangles to fill the vertical gaps
for row in range(grid_size):
    for col in range(1, grid_size):  # Exclude the first column
        x = col * (square_size + gap)
        y = row * (square_size + gap)
        green_rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), -gap, square_size, edgecolor='none', facecolor='green')
        ax.add_patch(green_rectangle)

# Add red rectangles to fill the horizontal gaps
for row in range(1, grid_size):  # Exclude the first row
    for col in range(grid_size):
        x = col * (square_size + gap)
        y = row * (square_size + gap)
        red_rectangle = plt.Rectangle((x, y), square_size, -gap, edgecolor='none', facecolor='red')
        ax.add_patch(red_rectangle)

# Set the aspect of the plot to be equal, so squares appear as squares
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Set limits to accommodate the gaps
ax.set_xlim(0, grid_size * (square_size + gap) - gap)
ax.set_ylim(0, grid_size * (square_size + gap) - gap)

# Remove spines and ticks
ax.axis('off')
# Show the plot
plt.show()


